# How to Access Element in this XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm no longer a coder, last time I coded C language was 12 years ago.

I needed to access the FirstName in this XML:

```
<Customer>
<data_0>
     <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
</data_0>
<data_1>
    <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
</data_1>
<data_2>
    <FirstName>Luke</FirstName>
</data_2>
</Customer>
```

Strangely, the XML returned by my API call is not a regular array, rather displayed in data_0, data_1, data_2 and so forth.

I wonder what kind of code would work to access the FirstName in each dataset?

I was hoping the following code would work but didn't:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($results);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
$data="data_".$i;

echo $xml->Customer[0]->$data->FirstName;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I meant echo $xml->Customer->$data->FirstName;

Comment: Hey @FirstOne, it worked, somehow I don't know how I messed up earlier, I tested this way once but it didnt' work, now it worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: Converted comment into an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
echo $xml->Customer[0]->$data->FirstName;
```

with

```
echo $xml->$data->FirstName;
```

See it in action [here](https://eval.in/606598).

---

If you `print_r($xml)`, you'll see that this is the structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [data_0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Michael
        )

    [data_1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Jack
        )

    [data_2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Luke
        )

)
```

So you already have each `data_X` at hand, you just have to get them.

---

You could also use a `foreach` to loop the elements, take a look:

```
foreach($xml as $k => $v){
    echo "[$k]: " . $v->FirstName . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
[data_0]: Michael
[data_1]: Jack
[data_2]: Luke
```

Comment: Thank a bunch, foreach loop is the one I need to use ;)

Comment: Just be careful about that foreach. If you have other elements that don't have `FirstName` as a child, it won't 'really' work. Take a look: [https://eval.in/606599](https://eval.in/606599)

Comment: the foreach loop isn't working as it supposed to. I guess because I didn't provide the full XML file structure, it has extra nodes, so now I'm getting [connection_status]: 
[operation_status]: 
[Customer]:

Comment: So the safe approach is use for loop instead of foreach loop correct?

Comment: @EricChen You could do something like this: [https://eval.in/606602](https://eval.in/606602). But maybe RomanPerekhrest's answer fits better for you (since this is starting to get overcomplicated)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `SimpleXMLElement::xpath` function:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($results);
// "//../FirstName" - relative path to 'FirstName' items
foreach ($xml->xpath("//../FirstName") as $name) {
    echo (string) $name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
Michael
Jack
Luke
```

Comment: This solution seems better. Mine just 'fixes the issue'. +1